# Color box with rounded corners

Tags: color, tcolorbox, mdframed

Here's my MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{LightLavender}{Lavender!40!}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{LightLavender}{hello} world

\end{document}
```

It produces something like this:

[image]

I'm wondering if it's possible to have the box have rounded corners. Ideally a solution would work in both text and math modes because I sometimes use it in equations to help designate which terms are alike/cancel out.

Comment: `mdframed` also having better features....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`tcolorbox`, with use in math environment(s):

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\colorlet{LightLavender}{Lavender!40!}
\tcbset{on line, 
        boxsep=4pt, left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=LightLavender,  
        highlight math style={enhanced}
        }

\begin{document}
\tcbox{Hello} world! $\tcbhighmath{c^2} = a^2 + b^2$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice...and the boxes are inline with the formula. +1.

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome thanks! I didn't know you could add the dvipsnames option to the article class either, so that's an added bonus.

Comment: @Zarko how would you recommend doing this if I wanted to have multiple color highlights?

Comment: @NateStemen, this is new question which in comment is not visible well to others, who has similar problems. So it will be nice ask it as such :-). It can be solved on different way, the simplest seems to be add desired color as option to `\tcbox` or `\tcbhighmath`.

Comment: I've noticed that `\tcbox` increases the line height when highlighting some words in a long text. Any suggestion to avoid this extra margin? Thanks.

Comment: @unDavide, in such a cases you need redesign `tcbox` (define smaller `boxsep`). For more, I advice to ask new question, where you provide an MWE, which reproduce your problem. On it people can answer with solutions for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Zarko, I've posted a new question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696253/line-height-with-inline-tcolorbox).

Answer (score 4):

Use `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{LightLavender}{Lavender!40!}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\tcbox[on line,boxsep=0pt,left=2pt,right=2pt,top=2pt,bottom=2pt,colback=LightLavender]{hello} world

\end{document}
```

[image]