# Why do I get a "Missing number" error when using tcbox in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, errors, tcolorbox, compilation-error

I get error messages "Missing number, treated as zero" and unwanted spaces before the tcbox'es in math mode (text mode is fine). What am I doing incorrectly? My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\renewcommand{\equiv}{\text{\tcbox{=}}}
\begin{document}
$w - 2\equiv v\equiv v$
\strut \newline
\strut \newline
\strut \newline
w - 2\equiv v\equiv v
\end{document}
```

In overleaf + pdfLaTeX, it yields the following (1st line is where the problem is, 2nd line as expected).

[image]

**EDIT**

I have reduced @Zarko's answer a bit to show what options were used to eliminate the problems:

```
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{on line,
    left=-1pt,right=-1pt,top=1pt,bottom=0pt,
    highlight math style={enhanced}}
\renewcommand{\equiv}{\;\tcbhighmath{-->}\;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you after. I guess that you actually looking for something like this:

[image]

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568880/color-box-with-rounded-corners/568900#568900) your MWE can be rewritten as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{on line,    % borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568880/
        boxsep=0pt, % left=1pt,right=1pt,top=1pt,bottom=1pt,
        colframe=gray,colback=gray!10,
        highlight math style={enhanced}  % <---
        }
\renewcommand{\equiv}{\;\tcbhighmath{=}\;}

\begin{document}
$w - 2 \equiv v \equiv v$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ahhhhh...Then it is true that I have not understood the question :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, question is quite cryptic ... I was lucky in guessing :-)

Comment: @Zarko perfect guess, thank you!