# Arrow from inner tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox

I am trying to connect two inner tcolorboxes with a arrow.
I have also seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/571886/drawing-arrows-from-one-tcolorbox-to-another) and [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/390962/add-arrow-between-two-tcolorboxes), unfortunately it was not helpful with my problem.
A minimum example is below. I am grateful for any help. It should be noted that I would like to find a solution that does not require the manual setting of coordinates, since the target diagrams are complex. Each node has its own height, only the width of the nodes is constant [image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning}

\newtcolorbox{rosnode}[1]{
    colback=white!85!gray,
    colframe=gray,
    coltitle=white,
    boxrule=2pt,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    sharp corners=all,
    center title,
    % lower separated=false,
    width=5cm,
    title={#1}
}

\newtcolorbox{rosservice}[1]{
    colback=white!85!gray,
    colframe=gray,
    coltitle=white,
    boxrule=2pt,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    arc=0.4mm,
    center title,
    % lower separated=false,
    left skip=-0.3cm,
    right skip=-0.3cm,
    title={#1}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
    \node(Node1) {
        \begin{rosnode}{Node1}
            Box 1 longer text text text text text
            \begin{rosservice}{InnerBox1}
                Box text
            \end{rosservice}
        \end{rosnode}
    };
    \node(Node2) [right=of Node1] {
        \begin{rosnode}{Node2}
            Box 2 text 
            \begin{rosservice}{InnerBox2}
                Box text
            \end{rosservice}
        \end{rosnode}
    };
    \draw[gray,line width=0.8mm,-{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}] (Node1) -- (Node2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! I am unsure whether this complexity with placing `tcolorbox`es inside Ti*k*Z nodes is really needed, but I will keep your set up since I don't know what you want to achieve with this.

In order to refer to the outer frame of a `tcolorbox` using Ti*k*Z macros such as `\draw`, you can use the `remember as` option on the relevant `tcolorbox`. You also need to add the option `enhanced` for this `tcolorbox`. Having done this, you can refer to this box using a `tikzpicture` with the options `remember picture, overlay`.

See the following adjustments to your original code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning}

\newtcolorbox{rosnode}[1]{
    colback=white!85!gray,
    colframe=gray,
    coltitle=white,
    boxrule=2pt,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    sharp corners=all,
    center title,
    % lower separated=false,
    width=5cm,
    title={#1}
}

\newtcolorbox{rosservice}[2][]{
    enhanced,
    colback=white!85!gray,
    colframe=gray,
    coltitle=white,
    boxrule=2pt,
    halign=center,
    valign=center,
    arc=0.4mm,
    center title,
    % lower separated=false,
    left skip=-0.3cm,
    right skip=-0.3cm,
    title={#2},
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm, every node/.style={inner sep=0,outer sep=0}]
    \node(Node1) {
        \begin{rosnode}{Node1}
            Box 1 longer text text text text text
            \begin{rosservice}[remember as=InnerBox1]{InnerBox1}
                Box text
            \end{rosservice}
        \end{rosnode}
    };
    \node(Node2) [right=of Node1] {
        \begin{rosnode}{Node2}
            Box 2 text 
            \begin{rosservice}[remember as=InnerBox2]{InnerBox2}
                Box text
            \end{rosservice}
        \end{rosnode}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw[gray, line width=0.8mm, -{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}] (InnerBox1.east) -- (InnerBox2.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In this case, it might be a good idea to change the color of the arrow to make it more visible.