# Line height with inline tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, line-spacing

I have implemented the suggestions from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568880/color-box-with-rounded-corners/568900) using a `tcolorbox` to highlight inline with rounded corners.

I've noticed that the box has vertical margins I am unable to remove, and it pushes the lines before and after it further away.

[image: screenshot]

MVE as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{relsize}

\definecolor{kode-color}{RGB}{240,240,240}
\newcommand{\codesize}{\smaller[0.75]} 

\newcommand{\kode}[1]{%
    \tcbox[on line,
        show bounding box,
        boxsep=4pt, 
        left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
        colframe=white,colback=kode-color
    ]{\texttt{\codesize #1}}%
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea \kode{commodo consequat} duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

Any idea how to avoid it?
I'm not so keen on using `tcolorbox`, as I've read it gives headaches with line-breaking. What I'm using now is this:

```
\definecolor{kode-color}{RGB}{140,40,40}
\newcommand{\codesize}{\smaller[0.75]} % requires "relsize"
% File extension
\newcommand{\kode}[1]{\colorbox[HTML]{EEEEEE}{\color{kode-color}{{\texttt{\codesize #1}}}}}
```

It is simpler, with no line-height or line-breaking problems (AFAIK), but no rounded corners either. I'm trying to understand whether I can add a bit of eye candy without ruining it functionally.

Thanks!

Comment: For `\tcbox`, it's caused by your setting `boxsep=4pt`. For `\colorbox`, it's caused by `\fboxsep` which defaults to 3pt.

Comment: I need some internal padding. I can set `boxsep=0pt`, and the line height is indeed OK, but the box is too tight. Setting `left`, `right`, `top`, and `bottom` gets me back to square one, alas.

Comment: Box extrusion options (documented in `tcolorbox` package manual, sec. 4.15.5) won't enlarge bounding box. You can try with `boxsep=0pt, left=0pt, right=0pt, top=0pt, bottom=0pt, extrude by=2pt` (extrusion option must be the last).

Comment: @unDavide, any news?

Answer (score 0):

For what you like to achieve it seems to be better to use `soul` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
\hl{Commodo consequat} 
duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have different highlighting color, put in preamble or local group with highlighted text `\sethlcolor{<desired color>}`